# Is Wilcoxon Test appropriate for paired categorical data?

Tags: categorical-data, nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank, mcnemar-test

There is currently a story in the [news in the UK](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-49036145) about negative effects of puberty blockers in children: 'It showed that after a year on puberty blockers, there was a significant increase found in those answering the statement "I deliberately try to hurt or kill myself"'.  It links to the [data](https://tavistockandportman.nhs.uk/documents/142/board-papers-2015-06.pdf), the numbers are found in table 4 (page 53):
[image: Table 4, Self harm from the Youth Self Report using Wilcoxon Test]

My reading of this is that 13% of 30 people said "I deliberately try to hurt or kill myself" before the drug treatment, and 39% of the same 30 people said that at T1 (during the treatment), and this change is significant, p=0.035.  The obvious way to analyse this would be McNemar's test.  However at the top of the table it says "using Wilcoxon Test".  This could be referring to the Wilcoxon signed-rank test, but I am only aware of this being appropriate when the response variable is continuous.

Which Wilcoxon test would be appropriate for this sort of data?  Is it likely that this is being used here? Or did the authors make a mistake?

Comment: I can just say that I'm with you on this one. Unclear to me how the Wilcoxon test was used. Arguably the Wilcoxon test is applicable to ordinal (non-continuous) data, taking bindings into account appropriately, but even that doesn't seem to fit the situation here.